# C# DataView.RowFilter issue filtering SQL with using the AS syntax

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm not new to programming but am just getting into c# and writing my first program.

My objective is an asset incident tracking system, basic and to the point with exactly what we need and nothing more. I'm starting small and working my way up.

I've so far successfully connected to and queried an MS Access database and projected a table into a DataGridView object.

I have successfully filtered the results as well but am trying to move on now. The names of my columns are not what I want displayed as my column headers in the DataGridView so I modified my query to include the as syntax.

```
SELECT serialnumber as `Serial Number`, owner as `Owner`, datesubmitted as `Date Submitted`,dateprocessed as `Date Processed`,technician as `Technician`,status as `Status`,datereturned as `Date Returned`,problem as `Problem` from incidents
```

So the way I'm filtering is with a drop down object to select the column and a text box to search for a value in the desired column. I manually entered the items in the drop down so they are not dynamically populated. Before my 'AS' syntax, I was using if/else if's to tranlate my pretty drop down text to the actually column names and that worked. After my change to the query, I was getting column not found errors so I changed my my syntax in the if/else if blocks to search for the 'pretty' column names, no go.

So then I figured, get rid of them all together and came up with this:

```
dv.RowFilter = string.Format("'{0}' LIKE '%{1}%'", searchCriteria.Text, textSearch.Text);
```

Can anyone help or point me in the right direction? I haven't been lucky in finding or maybe just even understanding search results that I've come across.

Here is the whole program so far.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace IncidentTracking
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private DataTable dt;
        private OleDbConnection connString;
        private OleDbCommand command;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'assetTrackingDataSet.incidents' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.incidentsTableAdapter.Fill(this.assetTrackingDataSet.incidents);
            connString = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\AssetTracking.accdb");
            command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT serialnumber as `Serial Number`, owner as `Owner`, datesubmitted as `Date Submitted`,dateprocessed as `Date Processed`,technician as `Technician`,status as `Status`,datereturned as `Date Returned`,problem as `Problem` from incidents", connString);
            connString.Open();
            using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command))
            {
                dt = new DataTable("incidents");
                da.Fill(dt);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            }

        }

        private void textSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;

            dv.RowFilter = string.Format("'{0}' LIKE '%{1}%'", searchCriteria.Text, textSearch.Text);

            if (textSearch.Text == "")
            {
                dv.RowFilter = null;
            }

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dv.ToTable();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to specify the first parameter in your Like with an actual field name what is the value of `searchCriteria.Text`

Comment: That will be a column name. ie, serial number, owner, etc... For instance, with the "serialnumber" column. If I try filtering with "serialnumber like..." I receive column not found. If I filter with "'serial number' like..." I don't get an error but nothing comes up in the datagridview, everything just disappears.

Comment: I believe I'm doing it the cheap way but I guess I've resolved it. I removed my as syntax from the query and the same function renamed the column headers with:

    dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Serial Number"; and so on